# update imageView not the good one

Tags: android, image

I try to update my imageiew using buttons

```
private void visitUpdateImage(int type) {

if(type == 0){
    if(ecran != 1){
        ecran--;
    }
}
else if(type == 1){
    if(ecran != nbEcrans){
        ecran++;
    }
}

int[] images = new int[nbEcrans];
images[0] = R.drawable.ecran1;
images[1] = R.drawable.ecran2;
images[2] = R.drawable.ecran3;
images[3] = R.drawable.ecran4;
images[4] = R.drawable.ecran5;
images[5] = R.drawable.ecran6;
images[6] = R.drawable.ecran7;

ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

image.setImageResource(images[ecran - 1]);

System.out.println(ecran);
```

}

The begining is good but images[5] il loading ic_launcher instead of ecran6 and the image[6] load nothing

I have all my ecrans in all my drawable repositories

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing (Your conditions are wrong) Use:

```
if(type == 0){
    if(ecran != 0){ //min is 0
        ecran--;
    }
}
else if(type == 1){
    if(ecran != nbEcrans-1){ //max is nbEcrans-1
        ecran++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ant try also to clean the project. You should also try to move your ecran images to one drawable folder (drawable-hdpi for example) and remove them from all other folders and run it.